# Text with unicode CODES not displaying correctly in Python 3.7

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.7

After being hours checking every stackoverflow post related to this, I'm pulling my hair to solve what should be a very simple thing...

I have a text file with unicode codes (not characters, codes), for example:

> "Edward escribi\u00c3\u00b3 la biograf\u00c3\u00ada de su autor
>   favorito"

This string should be displayed as:

> "Edward escribió la biografía de su autor favorito"

If I load the file as I normally do, I will just see the unicode strings when I print the loaded text:

```
import io
chars = io.open(fb_json_path, encoding='utf-8').read().strip()
```

This prints: "Edward escribi\u00c3\u00b3 la biograf\u00c3\u00ada de su autor favorito". It's the same if I remove the encoding parameter.

I guess I need to tell Python to interprete the codes in the string and display them as utf-8 characters, but I don't get how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the quotes in the file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no, the file does not contain those quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do that in two steps:

First, we read the file with `encoding='unicode_escape'` to convert all of the `\uxxxx`.

Then, we convert this to utf-8 by encoding it transparently to a bytes object (with `latin-1` codec) and convert it to text again, decoding as utf-8

```
with open('text.txt', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
    #Edward escribiÃ³ la biografÃ­a de su autor favorito

    # Now we convert it to utf-8
    text = text.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    print(text)
    # Edward escribió la biografía de su autor favorito
```

Comment: Beautiful !! Thanks so much @Thierry !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the input is somehow garbled by wrong encoding.

`C3 93` are the UTF-8 encoding bytes for the `ó`([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d3/index.htm)).

run in Python 3 console

```
>>> text = "Edward escribi\u00c3\u00b3 la biograf\u00c3\u00ada de su autor favorito"
>>> text.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
'Edward escribió la biografía de su autor favorito'
```